# How to bind observableCollection to DataGrid via ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, binding, observablecollection

I've listVIew on my first page. As soon as user double clicks on one item from that listVIew, I'm supposed to show a GridView where they can add/update/delete item. I've my code working until double click. I also see correct binding on my GridView and also getting correct count of items from database but UI doesn't show anything. Each individual item has a binding error of 40. Please help!

This is the error when I snoop QuestionCode:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'QuestionCode' property not found on 'object' ''Char' (HashCode=4390979)'. BindingExpression:Path=QuestionCode; DataItem='Char' (HashCode=4390979); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

This is my xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="gridQuestionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=CheckListQuestions}" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Question Code" MinWidth="70">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3,0,8,0" Text="{Binding QuestionCode, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding QuestionCode, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is my code behind:

```
public partial class CheckListQuestionWindow : Window
{
    private string _checklistCode = string.Empty;
    private CheckListQuestionViewModel _viewModel;
    public CheckListQuestionWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CheckListQuestionWindow(string checkListCode) : this()
    {
        _checklistCode = checkListCode;
        if (_viewModel == null)
            _viewModel = new CheckListQuestionViewModel(_checklistCode);

        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<ChecklistQuestion> CheckListQuestions { get; set; }

    public CheckListQuestionViewModel(string code)
    {
        var list = ChecklistQuestionList.GetChecklistQuestionList(code);
        CheckListQuestions = list;
       //here i'm getting correct count of checklistquestions but there's no data
    }
```

This is my Model:

```
public string QuestionCode
{
    get { return GetProperty(QuestionCodeProperty); }
    set { SetProperty(QuestionCodeProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=CheckListQuestions}"
```

by

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckListQuestions}"
```

or just

```
ItemsSource="{Binding CheckListQuestions}"
```

---

When using `Source=CheckListQuestions`, the ItemsSource property gets the string "CheckListQuestions" as value, which is an `IEnumerable<char>`. Hence the error `'QuestionCode' property not found on 'object' ''Char'`

---

Also make sure that `CheckListQuestions` is a public property, i.e.

```
public ObservableCollection<ChecklistQuestion> CheckListQuestions { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
ObservableCollection<ChecklistQuestion> CheckListQuestions { get; set; }
```

Comment: That fixes QuestionCode error but the itemsSource has the same binding error 40.
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CheckListQuestions' property not found on 'object' ''CheckListQuestionViewModel' (HashCode=54204373)'. BindingExpression:Path=CheckListQuestions; DataItem='CheckListQuestionViewModel' (HashCode=54204373); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='gridQuestionList'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses! changing it to public worked!